# What kinds of HTML tags come in pairs and what not in pairs?

Tags: html

What kinds of HTML tags come in pairs and what not in pairs?

[Wikipedia about HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) says:

> HTML tags most commonly come in pairs like `<h1>` and `</h1>`, although some tags represent empty elements and so are unpaired, for example `<img>`

What does it mean by "empty elements"? `<img>` represents image embedding which isn't it nonempty element?

Thanks.

Comment: Empty means the element has no content (other elements, text) _inside_ it.

Comment: what do you mean "inside it"? Does an image or its link not have content?

Comment: Further down on that WikiPedia page it says, _“Empty elements may enclose no content”_.

Comment: `<h1>This text is INSIDE of the element.</h1>`

Comment: `img` is considered a “replaced inline element”, emphasis on the first word here, _replaced_. The element itself does not have content, but is replaced with image data taken from an external source.

Comment: The HTML[5] living specification covers which tags fall under what category - mainly void elements (which cannot even technically have a self-closing tag).

Answer (score 3):

All tag come in pairs except for [Void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), which at the time of this writing include: area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, and wbr.

Comment: thanks. but why not `<img> img_link </img>` so there is content, instead of putting the link inside the bracket as attribute `<img src="img_link">`?

Comment: @Tim "Because that is how it is defined." And making up new syntax is forbidden (or rather, unlikely to be rendered correctly across browsers). HTML derives from SGML which is much less "uniform" than XML - mainly certain elements specifically have context.

Comment: @user: isn't designing `<img>` as pairs more consistent with most tags that are paired?

Comment: @Tim It *does not matter* what is "more consistent". It only matter *what is*. So "yes, it may/would/could be more consistent" and "no, it doesn't change anything regarding the validity of HTML".

Comment: @user: it is designed by some human, it is not just what it is. it is what it is for some reason.

Comment: Well the content in between the tags is what gets shown to the end user.  So img  makes sense as a void tag.  The src is an attribute of img, letting the browser know how to display it.  Essentially, if you take out all the html tags from the body, you should have just human-readable text.  If that helps.

Comment: @Dan: Must what is between a pair of paired tags be text?

Comment: @Tim Of course not, but such comment "discussion" has diverged into the realm of what-if's.. the linked specification contains all the relevant details for what is. There are plenty of articles on the questions dealing with the "messy" SGML origins of HTML and backwards-compatibility of such.

Comment: @user: I am expecting something like Dan's last comment.

Comment: This answer is specific to HTML5 and uses HTML5 terminology (which differs from earlier terms), without stating this.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page (as of now) is confused and confusing, and it uses old HTML terminology: the term “[empty element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.3)” as used up to HTML 4.01 and various XHTML specifications was replaced by “[void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements)” in HTML5. These terms are used to describe elements that *cannot* have any content, in the technical meaning for “content” as defined in HTML. When HTML appears as linear text, as serialized, using tags, this “content” is what appears between the start tag and the end tag (either of which may be implied for some elements). In the Document Object Model, “content” consists of the child nodes of an element that are element nodes or text nodes.

Emptyness does not imply invisibility. For example, `<hr>` is normally rendered as a horizontal rule. But the element is empty because its definition does not allow any content for the element

“Void element” is introduced in HTML5 by a list: area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr. However, this is meant to mean the elements with content model that allows no content; the list follows from this. The definitions of these elements specify “Content model: Empty.”

An element is an empty/void element if it is declared so in an applicable HTML specification. The definition of each element indicates its content model (allowed content).

“Empty element” is (or was) an element with `EMPTY` declared content in the formal syntax. As such, it was simply a syntactic concept: an empty element *cannot* have any content (any elements or any text except whitespace) between the start tag and the end tag. According to HTML rules except XHTML, the end tag *must* be omitted (implied), whereas in XHTML, an empty element may be written either with the end tag present, e.g. `<br></br>`, or using a special syntax where a slash in the start tag makes it act as an end tag, too, e.g. `<br/>`. The latter is recommended in [clause C.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2) of XHTML 1.0.

HTML5 has two syntaxes (serializations, linearizations): classic HTML syntax and XHTML syntax. In the former, old HTML rules for empty elements apply to void elements, e.g. no end tag is allowed for `<br>`. However, for compatibility, a slash is allowed as in XHTML, e.g. `<br/>`, but it has no effect. In the XHTML syntax, all XML syntax rules apply, so `<br>` alone is fatally invalid (well-formedness error), and either `<br></br>` or `<br/>` must be used.